# JSON javascript dataObject to use in a library (Timeline.js)

Tags: javascript, json, timeline.js

I saved a response made by a @restcontroller in a JavaScript variable.

The response you get invoking an URL like localhost:8080/JSORresponse is a JSONresponseTimeline(B), B is a Bean.

The library I'm using is [timelineJS](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS#start-at-end)  . That's the interested part of the documentation:

> **Source**
>
> `source` should be either the path to the JSON resource to load, or a
>   JavaScript object corresponding to the Timeline model.
>
> Here is an example using a data object:
>
> ```
>  var dataObject = {timeline: {headline: "Headline", type: ... }}
>     createStoryJS({
>         type:       'timeline',
>         width:      '800',
>         height:     '600',
>         source:     dataObject,
>         embed_id:   'my-timeline'
>     });
> ```
>
> If source is a string, we will try to automatically recognize
>   resources that are Twitter searches, Google Spreadsheets or Storify
>   stories. Failing that, we assume the source is either JSON or JSONP.
>   If string matches on .jsonp, we will treat it as JSONP, otherwise, we
>   will append ?callback=onJSONP_Data. See more details below.

My code is as follows, but something doesn't seem to work, because I get a full blank page without my timeline (it is correctly set, and works with a mocked JSON). I don't get any errors in the console. Does anybody have an advice about how to solve this problem? (`beerS` is the exact representation of the JSON I need to use)

```
var beer;
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/timeline",function(json){
    beer = json;   
    checkDrink();                
});         

function checkDrink() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(beer));
    var beerS = JSON.stringify(beer)
    var timeline_config = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        source: beer
    }
}
```

if I do THIS the timeline work fine

```
  var beer;
      $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/timeline",function(json){
          beer = json;   
          checkDrink();                
      });         

      function checkDrink() {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(beer));
          var beerS = JSON.stringify(beer)

          var timeline_config = {
           width: "100%",
           height: "100%",
           source: "../../resources/js/test_extra_html.json"
          }
      }   


      var timeline_config = {
       width: "100%",
       height: "100%",
       source: "../../resources/js/test_extra_html.json"
      }
```

obviously with the informations inside "test extra html" and not the JSON from "beer"

I additionally put all the jsp front page here to help you understand

```
 <head>
    <title>Timeline JS Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="TimelineJS example">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Style-->
    <style>
      html, body {
       height:100%;
       padding: 0px;
       margin: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements--><!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- BEGIN Timeline Embed -->
      <div id="timeline-embed"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      var beer;
      $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/timeline",function(json){
          beer = json;   
          checkDrink();                
      });         

      function checkDrink() {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(beer));
          var beerS = JSON.stringify(beer)

          var timeline_config = {
           width: "100%",
           height: "100%",
           source: "../../resources/js/test_extra_html.json"
          }
      }   


      var timeline_config = {
       width: "100%",
       height: "100%",
       source: "../../resources/js/test_extra_html.json"
      }


      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/storyjs-embed.js"></script>
      <!-- END Timeline Embed-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you are not doing anything with `timeline_config`.

Comment: sorry question not clear, I have configured all the library and html page, but they are working, the problem is if I have all inside that function the timeline does not show, now i update the question with more code

Comment: I assume it's similar to your previous problem: The timeline thingy gets initialized before `timeline_config` is set.  You have to initialize it inside the callback. But given that `source` can be a URL, why are you using `getJSON` at all and not just set `source` to `http://localhost:8080/timeline` ?

Comment: From the documentation you posted, it assumes it's a URL because you are passing it a JSON string and tries to load it? You should pass in the parsed JSON, `beer`, instead of the JSON string

Comment: Ok there was a problem with the JSON when i tryed to put only the URL in source, but now I re-tryed and it's working, thank you all ;)